# Blazor server side upload file > 28.6MB functionality

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

Hi I want to ask how to configure blazor server side app to allow upload file greater than 28.6MB (Size bazed on this article: https://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/).

I'm using BlazorInputFile and Tewr.Blazor.FileReader. Everything works fine while file size is smaller then about 23 MB. Bigger files hangs application. Both solutions stops when reading into memorystream occurs.

```
 MemoryStream ms;
                using (ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await file.Data.CopyToAsync(ms); <- STOPS HERE
                    ms.Dispose();
                }
```

or

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = await file.CreateMemoryStreamAsync(100 * 1024 * 1024)) <-STOPS HERE
                {
                    // Sync calls are ok once file is in memory
                }
```

I tried multiple settings like:

```
services.AddSignalR(e =>
{
    e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
});

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = null;
    await next.Invoke();
});

services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddHubOptions(o => o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024);
```

but none of them works.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is still the case but previously I've had to add a web.config file, even though they're not actually used in .net core and had to add the following entries:

```xml
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- This will handle requests up to 50MB -->
        <!--<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />-->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```